# Deploying Firebase Functions with proper IAM permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am running into problems deploying to firebase functions this is my first deploy on this project. However I have never had any issues in the past. This is the error I am getting.

```
Deployment error.
Build failed: Unable to build your function due to VPC Service Controls. The Cloud Build 
service account associated with this function needs an appropriate access level on the 
service perimeter. Please grant access to the Cloud Build service account: 
'844843400202@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com' by following the instructions at
 https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-access-level#members-example.
```

I have enabled Cloud Functions Developer permissions on my `xxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`.

roles: 
 Editor 
 Admin 
 Service Account User 
 Cloud Functions Developer 
 Cloud Build Service Account 
 
 luck

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#functions), in order to deploy functions following two roles are necessary: `Cloud Functions Admin`, `Service Account User role`. Could you try that and let me know if it works?

Comment: I am still getting this error message why is it referring to vpc service controls when I don't use vpc services.

Comment: I understand that you are not using VPC services but could you please try the steps mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/using-vpc-service-controls#grant-build-access) and let me know if it works for you? It is a work around regarding the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you this worked could you explain why I was getting this error in the first place I have setup a number of firebase projects and never had to do this step

Comment: What comes to my mind is that maybe the organization policies are limiting the service accounts permissions in this specific project.

Answer (score 0):

With firebase-tools version 12.7.0, the following predefined gcp roles allow you to deploy firebase functions without having to resort to basic role owner or editor.

1. roles/cloudfunctions.admin
2. roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor
3. roles/secretmanager.viewer
4. roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
5. roles/firebase.viewer
6. roles/artifactregistry.repoAdmin

The "easiest" way to figure out missing permissions is to run your firebase cli command with the `--debug` flag and try to discern what the cli is calling and what permissions it would need.

Finally, these predefined roles probably are over provisioned and more than likely a custom role with the exact permissions needed would look much slimmer but since there's no documentation from Google, that would be a lot of trial and error to determine the exact permissions. Also, the next version of firebase-tools will more than likely break everything.

Comment: To add, you will need `roles/secretmanager.admin` role if you want the firebase cli to be able to update secrets policies.